# Need query for below conditions in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to refine below existing query as per conditions given below that:

Existing query:

```
Select * from table where 

(
        @payEffectiveDate > payEffectiveDate 
        AND payEffectiveDate    < payCancelDate 
)
```

In above query conditions mentioned in where clause should be executed only if below condition satisfy in where clause. I mean in where clause we need to check this below condition, if it satisfied then only it needs to go for above conditions.

```
@EffectiveDate >    payEffectiveDate  
        AND @EffectiveDate  < payCancelDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine them with `AND`

```
select   * 
from     Table 
where    (@EffectiveDate > payEffectiveDate 
                              AND @EffectiveDate  < payCancelDate)
          AND 
         (@payEffectiveDate > payEffectiveDate 
                              AND @payEffectiveDate < payCancelDate)
```

`AND` clause ensures that both the conditions around it must be true.

If the fields have data type `DateTime` then you can do this too

```
select   * 
from     Table 
where    (@EffectiveDate between payEffectiveDate AND payCancelDate)
          AND (@payEffectiveDate between payEffectiveDate AND payCancelDate)
```